# Timber causing fatal error in ImageHelper.php

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

Timber support question.
Blog author pages (/blog/authors/author-name/) are throwing this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: unlink(): Argument #1 ($filename) must be of type string, WP_Error given

The error originates from ImageHelper (timber/lib/ImageHelper.php) line 382

```
 /**
 * downloads an external image to the server and stores it on the server
 *
 * @param string  $file the URL to the original file
 * @return string the URL to the downloaded file
 */
 public static function sideload_image( $file ) {
    $loc = self::get_sideloaded_file_loc($file);
    if ( file_exists($loc) ) {
        return URLHelper::file_system_to_url($loc);
    }
    // Download file to temp location
    if ( !function_exists('download_url') ) {
        require_once ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/file.php';
    }
    $tmp = download_url($file);
    preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpe?g|jpe|gif|png)\b/i', $file, $matches);
    $file_array = array();
    $file_array['name'] = basename($matches[0]);
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;
    // If error storing temporarily, unlink
    if ( is_wp_error($tmp) ) {
        @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']); //line 382
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
    }
    // do the validation and storage stuff
    $locinfo = pathinfo($loc);
    $file = wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, 
file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name']));
    return $file['url'];
}
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXMLj.png)

I'm using WordPress 6.0.2, PHP 8.0, Timber 3.4.2. I've upgraded to newest version using Composer.

The error has appeared only recently, I suspect with the latest WordPress update. Has anyone got any ideas for a potential fix? Thank you!

Comment: It must mean that `$tmp = download_url($file);` returned a WP_Error instance, instead of an actual file name/path. What this code does, does not appear to make much sense - it explicitly checks if `$tmp` is an instance of WP_Error, only to then try and unlink `$file_array['tmp_name']` - which _is_ `$tmp`, it was assigned just before ...

Answer (score 0):

change your condition like this (add ! operator to the condition)

```
if (!is_wp_error($tmp) ) {
    @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']); //line 382
    $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the error on line 382 but I'm getting a new one on line 387: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: file_get_contents(): Argument #1 ($filename) must be of type string, WP_Error given
in /wp-content/mu-plugins/timber/lib/ImageHelper.php on line 387

$file = wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name']));

Comment: if ( is_wp_error($tmp) ) {
        @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']); //line 382
        $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
    }else{
    // do the validation and storage stuff
    $locinfo = pathinfo($loc);
    $file = wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, 
    file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name']));
    return $file['url'];
}

Comment: Thanks @TLEMCANI Abdelkadir for fighting for this one! A combination of things have fixed the error:
 `if ( is_wp_error($tmp) ) { //commenting out line below due to fatal error 
   //@unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
   $file_array['tmp_name'] = ''; } else { // do the validation and storage stuff 
 $locinfo = pathinfo($loc);  $file = wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name'])); return $file['url'];  }`

Answer (score 0):

change your condition like this (add ! operator to the condition), and if the condition incorrect go to the next code

```
  if ( !is_wp_error($tmp) ) { 
     @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']); //line 382 

      $file_array['tmp_name'] = ''; 
  }else{
     // do the validation and storage stuff 
     $locinfo = pathinfo($loc); $file = 
     wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, 
     file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name'])); return 
     $file['url']; 
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( is_wp_error($tmp) ) {
            //commenting out line below due to fatal error 
            //@unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
            $file_array['tmp_name'] = ''; 
        } else { 
            // do the validation and storage stuff
             $locinfo = pathinfo($loc); 
             $file = wp_upload_bits($locinfo['basename'], null, file_get_contents($file_array['tmp_name'])); 
             return $file['url']; 
        }
```